# Proving $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

So let me pose the complete question:

> Show the following: 
>
> Let $f, g : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and differentiable on the interval (a,b) with $f(a) \ge g(a)$ and $f'(x) \ge g'(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, then it follows that $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

We started this semester with differentiation and MVT, but I am clueless how to approach this problem.

Now looking at the functions, it is evident that it should be true, since the $f'(x)$ is always greater than or equal to $g'(x)$, which implies the monotony of the functions and hence all values being greater in the original function. But that is as far as I could get.

Comment: Apply the MVT to the difference $f-g$ ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>It is trivial.</s> Let $h=f-g$, then $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$,
differentiable on $(a,b)$. Moreover, $h(a)\geq0$ and $h'(x)\geq0$
for all $x\in(a,b)$. Let $x\in(a,b]$ be arbitrary. By Mean Value
Theorem, there exists $\xi\in(a,x)$ such that $h(x)-h(a)=h'(\xi)(x-a)$.
Therefore, $h(x)=h(a)+h'(\xi)(x-a)\geq0$.

Comment: Always wrong when answering a question t9 say “it is trivial.” Reads as judgmental, even if not meant  as such.

Comment: Why is $\xi$ from the interval $(a,x)$ and not $(a,b)?

Comment: @ yousafe007 We are applying Mean Value Theorem for $h$ on $[a,x]$.